# bigCommerce customer api - Customer JWT for sso

Tags: bigcommerce

In my app ([node-bigcommerce-sdk](https://github.com/getconversio/node-bigcommerce)) my customers will need to login  as if they were on the bc store. I am able to verify that the provided email and password are correct. I cant find a method to exchange the user_id and my app credentials for a token that can be used in sso ([described here](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#customer-login-api))

I used the [python sdk](https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-python) before and the part I want to do now in nodejs is the following

```
bc_client = b.api.BigcommerceApi(client_id, store_hash, access_token)
login_token = sdk.customer_login_token.create(bc_client, customer.id)
```

#### so far (not working)

```
let token = jwt.encode({
    "iss": account.clientId,
    "iat": 123456789,
    "jti": "uid-"+uid,
    "operation": "customer_login",
    "store_hash": account.storeHash,
    "customer_id": uid,
}, account.secret, 'HS512');
let sso_url = `${account.entry_url}/login/token/${token}`
```

example token received

`eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJja244ZzN5Z3V4MmY0cG14ZWw0M2dqbmJjOTViZ2FrIiwiaWF0IjoxMjM0NTY3ODksImp0aSI6InVpZC0xIiwib3BlcmF0aW9uIjoiY3VzdG9tZXJfbG9naW4iLCJzdG9yZV9oYXNoIjoiMmJpaHByMnd2eiIsImN1c3RvbWVyX2lkIjoiMSJ9.n4lygAJtfqhcrHnGEWle1far-Ee69xrgym-HWFWWwNWXB1-hBziKC03SK_y8PYjLBL_n43Q6K07YH9ysSV5a4g`

`${account.entry_url}/login/token/${token}` results in an error message on the frontend `Invalid login. Please attempt to log in again.`

Comment: what is not working? which API isn't working and what is the error you receive?

Comment: `${account.entry_url}/login/token/${token}` results in an error message on the frontend `Invalid login. Please attempt to log in again.`

Comment: could it have something to do with `iat `. Dont really know how to set it

Comment: The iat should be the Unix timestamp in seconds. So in Node, you could use Math.floor(new Date() / 1000);